# Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function:

```
reportAdminActions.reportMemberList(project, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This function is called by another ajax operation like these:

```
reportMemberList: function(projectId, callback) {
    var projectDetail = new Object();
    projectDetail.projectId = projectId;
    var pluginArrayProject = new Array();
    pluginArrayProject.push(projectDetail);   
    $.ajax({
        url : ConfigCom.serverUrl + 'projectreportonmember',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(pluginArrayProject)
    }).always(function(data) {
        callback(data.responseText);
    });
}
```

I need return value to function defined area after ajax operation. But here I got a error

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Comment: I am not sure but i doubt it is because of your `JSONP`

Comment: Bad luck. It is not working when i removed JSONP.

Comment: could you please post the sample of your server response?

Comment: It is JSON Response [{"timesheet_user_id":"5","timesheet_hours":"4","name":"jagadeesh puthukkudi"},{"timesheet_user_id":"8","timesheet_hours":"7","name":"admin admin"},{"timesheet_user_id":"5","timesheet_hours":"2","name":"jagadeesh puthukkudi"}]

Answer (score 1):

Check the rest of your code for calls to `reportMemberList` and make sure you always call it with the callback as a parameter. If you omit the callback parameter anywhere (e.g. call `reportMemberList` with just the `projectId` parameter), the code above would parse correctly the other calls to the function with the callback would produce the error. (This was the solution for me.)

Answer (score 0):

guessing, but try to change your "jsonp" to "json". If you don't make cross-origin requests there, it should work

```
reportMemberList: function(projectId, callback) {
    var projectDetail = new Object();
    projectDetail.projectId = projectId;
    var pluginArrayProject = new Array();
    pluginArrayProject.push(projectDetail);   
    $.ajax({
        url : ConfigCom.serverUrl + 'projectreportonmember',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(pluginArrayProject)
    }).always(function(data) {
        callback(data.responseText);
    });
}
```

Comment: the code looks correct... could you give a URL where this error can be reproduced?